# What does 'database' mean in mySQL DBI->connect() data-source string?

Tags: database, perl, schema, dbi, mysql

Here is the template for connecting to a DB through DBI:

```
 $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $username, $password)
        or die $DBI::errstr;
```

and here is how $data_source is described:

```
dbi:DriverName:database=database_name;host=hostname;port=port
```

My understanding is that **host** + **port** identifies an instance of a mysqld *process* containing multiple *schemas*, and that a *schema* contains *tables*.  Where, then, in this heirarchy, is a "database"?  Sometimes it seems the word "database" refers to the mysqld instance, and other times to a schema.

**UPDATE 1:** Is it ever correct to refer to the "server" (e.g. a daemon process -- NOT a piece of hardware) to which clients connect on a TCP/IP port and send SQL requests as a "database"?  If not, what is it called?

Comment: MySQL calls schemas "databases". Why? Perhaps because if MySQL ever actually got anything right, it wouldn't be MySQL anymore.

Comment: Our company does about 30M$/year using MySQL to manage a direct marketing cooperative database, several tables of which contain between 100 million and 3.5 billion rows - what is it that it doesn't get right?

Comment: What doesn't it get right? There are a few things listed here for a start - http://use.perl.org/use.perl.org/_Smylers/journal/34246.html

Answer (score 0):

Perl::DBI can connect to many different venders' databases.  So the terms will vary, depending on which DB you are connecting to.  Some call it a schema, others call them databases.

For UPDATE1:  I'm assuming you mean the mysql.sock file?  See the mysql_socket option, explained here:  [How do I tell DBD::mysql where mysql.sock is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957916/how-do-i-tell-dbdmysql-where-mysql-sock-is)